# Firefox never finished loading JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

When I test my web app in Firefox, I have the never-ending connecting cirlce in my tab. Obviously Firefox is loading a script and there is something wrong. My html file should be opened locally, and in Chrome and IE it works fine. I mean, when script is done, the new web page is opened completely.

I shorten my code as much as I could, just to present the problem. Try to run it in Firefox and you will see.

What am I missing? I provide an HTML file and JavaScript file.

**test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="submit.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 140px; height: 28px; float: left;">Choose one number: </div>
        <div style="width: 46px; height: 28px; float: left;"><input type="submit" value="1" onClick="add1();"></div>
        <div style="width: 46px; height: 28px; float: left;"><input type="submit" value="2" onClick="add2();"></div>
        <div style="width: 46px; height: 28px; float: left;"><input type="submit" value="3" onClick="add3();"></div>
        <div style="width: 46px; height: 28px; float: left;"><input type="submit" value="4" onClick="add4();"></div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="CALCULATE" onClick="calculate();">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**submit.js**

```
var p1 = 0;

function add1() {
    p1 = 1; return p1;
}

function add2() {
    p1 = 2; return p1;
}

function add3() {
    p1 = 3; return p1;
}

function add4() {
    p1 = 4; return p1;
}

function calculate() {
    var sum = p1;
    document.write("Result is: " + sum + '<br />');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
document.open();
document.write("Result is: " + sum + '<br />');
document.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
document.close();
```

at the end

of your calculate() function. More info: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=331895